# How to add friend using branch.io deep linking in Android App

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

when i invite friend by sending link using branch.io,when a receiver click on link and install app and make account,he will automatically add in my friend list,How this is possible?

Comment: receive friend id from branch deeplink then send it this data through api

Comment: bro i am new to branch.io,can you elaborate this thing@Vikas Rai

Comment: what server are you using to store data?

Comment: Amazon server @Vikas Rai

Answer (score 1):

The invite link that you send should have the referring user as a link parameter. Once a user installs the app you can read the referring link parameters on first install https://docs.branch.io/apps/android/#read-deep-link

You will get the referring user details that you had set while creating the link. Use this info to add the user to the referring user's friend list.